# Bidirectional Child-Parent relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How to design JPA bi-direction relatinonship in this case?

```
 Class Person{
       List<Person> relatedPersons;

       Person parentPerson;

    }
```

I try next approach, but receive recursion.

```
  Class Person{
           @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentPerson")
           List<Person> relatedPersons;

           @ManyToOne
           @JoinTable(joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "related_person_id", referencedColumnName = "id") 
           Person parentPerson;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Class Person{
       @OneToMany (mappedBy = "parentPerson")
       List<Person> relatedPersons;

       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_PERSON_ID")
       Person parentPerson;
    }
```